# Android Studio Showing Textview only , without button or onclick

Tags: android, text

**I really want to get the date without button. and i don't know how?**[enter link description here](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/get-current-date-in-android-programmatically.html)

**i just want to get as text and doesn't have a button**

Answer (score 1):

OK. You can do it like this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void getCurrentDate() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy / MM / dd ");
        String strDate = "Current Date : " + mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
        display(strDate);
    }

    private void display(String num) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_date_view);
        textView.setText(num);
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you want the date simply call `getCurrentDate()`. And also make sure that the id of the `textView` is changed to yours.

Comment: You have just created a poorly designed method by indirectly binding `getCurrentDate()` to the `TextView`. A more universal method `getCurrentDate` would actually return the formatted date and `display` would call it and consume the return value. Just Say!